# differentiability in the origin of f(x,y)

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I have $$
f(x,y) = \cases{ \sqrt{xy}& if $x>0,y>0$ \\
       -\sqrt{xy}& if $x<0,y<0$ \\
0 }
$$
I want calculate directional derivative $D_vf(0,0)$ with $v=(1,1)$

f is not differentiable in the origin but do directional derivatives exist ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Your question is: does the limit $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to0}\frac{f(t,t)}t$ exist? What do you think?

Comment: $\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{f(t,t)}t=\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{|t|}t=1$ and $\lim_{t\to0^-}\frac{f(t,t)}t=\lim_{t\to0^-}\frac{-|t|}t=1$ so exist?

Comment: Yes, it does, What's the doubt?